# Отправка формы ajax

Tags: javascript

Как **собрать** имена полей в середине **div** **яваскриптом**? И еще значения. Если есть особенность работы с `select`, то и ее затронуть.

Comment: Я так понял, есть див, внутри него инпуты и селект, нужно получить их значения? jQuery можно использовать?

Comment: а если низя JQuery - не асилите?:)

Comment: jQuery нельзя)) поля с данными в середине дива. и они целиком динамические. поэтому их имена и надо собрать. при чем кроссбраузерно(getElementByTagName не прокатит)

Comment: вопрос закрыт. использование ChildNodes

Answer (score 1):

Может я Вас не так понял, но можно сделать так:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     function sbor(){
    var input1 = document.getElementById("name1");
    var input2 = document.getElementById("name2");
    var div1 = document.getElementById("div1");
    div1.innerHTML(+input1.value+'<br />'+input2.value);
    }
    </script>
    <div id="div1"></div>
<input type="text" id="name2"><br />
<input type="text" id="name2"><br />
<button onClick="sbor()">Собрать</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input id="someNameToSendToTheServer" type="text"/>
```

Чтобы получить значение инпута:

```
var example = document.getElementById("someNameToSendToTheServer");
// в example.value хранится текущее значение текущего елемента
// справедливо и для чекбоксов, и для селектов, и для textarea
```

про селект реально ничего не понял

Comment: для селектов кстати не справедливо) в IE

Answer (score 0):

Имеем

```
<div id="some">
    <input type="text">First</input>
    <!-- ... -->
    <input type="text">Second</input>
<div>
```

Получаем

```
inputs = $("div input").map(function () {
    return $(this).val();
}).get().join(", "));
```

В итоге `inputs = First Second`.